# Vue reload single element after promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a custom object with a property using a custom getter that returns a *promise if the value hasn't been fetched yet*, or the *value if it has*. Basically, lazy-loading this property.

Vue cannot tell automatically when that getter changes, because the returned value is a Promise object initially, and then that getter returns another object entirely when that value is fetched. **This is expected behavior** as those are pointer to two different objects.

To work around this, in my template, if the value is a `Promise`, I am trying to:

- Conditionally show "Loading..." text (works)
- Set a key on the element so that re-render can be narrowly targeted (works?)
- Add a `.then` to the `Promise` to update the key (works)
- Have just that element re-render (not updating on its own)

The simplified code looks like this:

```
//Where data is an array of objects
//Where columns is an array of strings matching to object keys in data objects

<template v-for="(row, i) in data" :key="i">
    <div class="row">
        <template v-for="column in columns" :key="column">
        <div v-if="(row[column] instanceof Promise)" :key="reload(row[column])">Loading...</div>
        <div v-else>{{row[column]}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

---

```
methods: {
    reload(promise){
        var watchMe = {done: false};
        promise.then(() => {
            console.log("This definitely happens!");
            watchMe.done = true;
        });
        return watchMe;
    }
}
```

So my assumption is that when the key changes, the div should re-evaluate, and given that it's no longer getting a `Promise`, it should re-render correctly.

If I put in a `this.$forceUpdate` inside the `then` callback, it works - but it re-renders the entire component, rather than just the one element, which is not ideal. **This means my object getter is working exactly as intended**, I'm not worried about that.

None of these have worked:

- I have tried watchMe as a primitive value (0, then doing a watchMe++ in the callback).
- I have tried deleting watchMe.done in the callback
- I have tried passing in `i` from the row and then doing `i++` in the callback to refresh just the row

Why is the changing of the key not triggering the re-render of that element? And how do I make it do that?

Comment: Are you loading more than one set of data? 

row[column] instanceof Promise

I would show the loader if a flag was set, and set the flag when the promise is fulfilled or rejected.

Comment: Can you post real or approximate code for the promise-returning lazy getter on the object?

Comment: Having the getter return different things (could be a promise or the actual object) is bad design. It should be consistent. If the thing is already loaded, then just return an already-resolved promise that wraps the value.

Comment: I agree with @DecadeMoon, maybe if you show us how your data looks we could help you to solve this problem in the best way. You should return only the values you want to show (or some `{ isLoading: true }` in the object) and when the promise is resolved - update the data, and vue will re-render the component for you

Comment: Following @DecadeMoon 's advice, I instead started returning a reference to an empty object and then populating that object later asynchronously, and that worked. I think the OP still stands separately though: why would changing the :key object not cause the element to reload?

Comment: @RandyHall You have set the key to an object, which I believe is not allowed, the key must be a string/number/symbol. But even if an object key were allowed here, you are only changing a property of that object and not the object itself (Vue isn't observing the object deeply). But *even* if it were doing a deep observation of that object, the object itself isn't reactive because you've created it on the fly and Vue won't magically make the object reactive in this context.